# Moving 2 steppers with an adafruit motor shield

Tags: arduino

I'm making a project and I send strings to the arduino from my pc using the serial port, the arduino reads them and depending of the string it moves one motor or another, this is the code:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>


AF_Stepper motor1(200, 1);
AF_Stepper motor2(200, 2);

String steps= "";

void forwardstep1() { 
  motor1.onestep(FORWARD, SINGLE);
}
void backwardstep1() { 
  motor1.onestep(BACKWARD, SINGLE);
}
void forwardstep2() { 
  motor2.onestep(FORWARD, SINGLE);
}
void backwardstep2() { 
  motor2.onestep(BACKWARD, SINGLE);
}

AccelStepper stepper1(forwardstep1, backwardstep1);
AccelStepper stepper2(forwardstep2, backwardstep2);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Stepper program!");
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(200.0);
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(200.0);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(100.0);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(100.0);

}

void loop() {

}

void serialEvent() {

  while(Serial.available()) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Echo:");
    Serial.write(inChar);
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      steps += (char)inChar;
    }
    if (inChar == 'u') {
      Serial.print("Up:" + steps);
      Serial.println();
      long POSITION = stepper1.currentPosition() + steps.toInt();
      stepper1.runToNewPosition(POSITION);
      steps = "";
      Serial.println();
    }
   if (inChar == 'U') {
      Serial.print("Up:" + steps);
      Serial.println();
      long POSITION = stepper2.currentPosition() + steps.toInt();
      stepper2.runToNewPosition(POSITION);
      steps = "";
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is when I move the stepper1 and then try to move the stepper2 it doesnt move anymore unless I reset the arduino.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to debug it progressively. First check whether you are able to control the position of each motors independently. You can write a simple function to check this. Just move the motors alternately with fixed steps. If both motors are working fine then you can move on to debug serial communication. However if motors doesn't work fine then check connections etc(hardware debugging). Also check initialization of steppers motors.

If this is working fine then you can check if you are able to receive correct response from you pc on arduino. Probably light up different leds whenever you receive new characters. In this way you can confirm that both you motor and serial communication can working fine.

Also since you are receive the position of motors from serial. I would recommend to check if you are correctly receiving the position. May be you should try first by just hardcoding fixed steps in your program and see if it work when you received'u' and 'U'.

```
void serialEvent() {
   static int fixed_step_1;
   static int fixed_step_2;
  while(Serial.available()) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Echo:");
    Serial.write(inChar);

    if (inChar == 'u') {
      Serial.print("Up:");
      long POSITION = stepper1.currentPosition() + fixed_steps_1;
      stepper1.runToNewPosition(POSITION);
      fixed_steps_1++;
      Serial.println();
    }
   if (inChar == 'U') {
      long POSITION = stepper2.currentPosition() + fixed_steps_2;
      stepper2.runToNewPosition(POSITION);
      fixed_steps_2++;
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

If above work fine then you know it is can case of conversion. Though all these steps will take time but you may exactly pin-point the issue.